# SpringBoot RestTemplate timeout when using LoadBalanced

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-ribbon

I am new to microservices and trying a demo project where I have one Customer micro service communicating with a CRUD micro service. I am using Eureka server for discovery. CRUD service has all the database operations defined and I am using RestTemplate to call services defined in CRUD service from Customer micro service.

[The overall flow is like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dC7Qu.png)

Please Note it also has Payment MS but it's not yet fully developed.

When I am using hardcoded url value in my Customer MS RestTemplate postForObject and when @LoadBalanced is not used.

```
rest.postForObject("http://localhost:8762/addCustomer", request, Customer.class);
```

**It works fine.**

**However** when I use @LoadBalanced in config file of RestTemplate, It gives the below error
(I have learned that I need to remove @EnableEurekaClient when using @LoadBalanced. Tried that, not working.)

> "trace": "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances available for
> localhost\n\tat
> org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:119)\n\tat
> org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:99)\n\tat
> org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerInterceptor.intercept(LoadBalancerInterceptor.java:58)\n\tat
> org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93)\n\tat
> org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:77)\n\tat
> org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)\n\tat
> org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:739)\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:674)\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:418)\n\tat
> com.ms.customer.controller.CustomerController.addCustomer(CustomerController.java:31)\n\tat
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)\n\tat
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\n\tat
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\n\tat
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93)\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\n\tat
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)\n\tat
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\n\tat
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)\n\tat
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)\n\tat
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\n\tat
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tat
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\n",

Also I am trying not to hardcode and using the RestTemplate like

```
rest.postForObject("http://CRUDSERVICE/addCustomer", request, Customer.class);
```

Where CRUDSERVICE is `spring.application.name` for CRUD service.

I am getting the same error like above but this time for CRUDSERVICE.

> No instances available for CRUDSERVICE

I need help for

1. How to avoid using hardcoding in RestTemplate
2. How to use ribbon with this project

Please refer to my github link for the project
[Github link](https://github.com/mohit1003/Microservice)